# Hide SliverAppBar when when app is started

Tags: flutter

I want to open SliverAppBar only when I pull down, SliverAppBar is hiding automatically when scrolling down, but when I open the app, I want the appbar to hide, and only appear when I pull down.

```
    body: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                title: Text('Pull down to create item'),
                floating: false,
                pinned: false,
              ),
             ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set `floating: true,` on [`SliverAppBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html)

```dart
SliverAppBar(
  title: Text('Pull down to create item'),
  floating: true,
  pinned: false,
),
```

Comment: More like you are looking for [RefreshIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator-class.html)